# Restkit: object mapping with xml

Tags: ios, xml-parsing, restkit, rkobjectmapping

I try to map the response xml into object and the xml looks like:

```
<list version="1.0">
  <meta>
    <type>resource-list</type>
  </meta>
  <resources start="0" count="168">
    <resource classname="Quote">
      <field name="name">Alpha</field>
      <field name="price">10</field>
    </resource>
    <resource classname="Quote">
      <field name="name">Beta</field>
      <field name="price">9</field>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</list>
```

What I want is `resources` part. I create the object model:

```
@interface Field : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *price;
@end
@interface Resources : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *count;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *resource;
@end
```

The problem is : I don't know how to set the mapping for `resource` of `Resources`. I once tried using mapping:

```
RKObjectMapping *objMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Field class]];
[objMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"name",@"price"]];</br>

RKObjectMapping *resourcesMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Resources class]];
[resourcesMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"count"]];
[resourcesMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"resource" toKeyPath:nil withMapping:objMapping]];

RKResponseDescriptor *descriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:resourcesMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"XXXXXX" keyPath:@"list.resources" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

After the mapping is finished, the `Resources` object is created. However the array `resource` of it is still nil.

How can I get the array of resource in the xml?
---Updated-----
I updated the code, which is

```
RKObjectMapping *objMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Field class]];
objMapping.forceCollectionMapping = YES;
[objMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"name":@"name.text"}];
```

I also update the respondscripter with keypath:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *descriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"XXXXX" keyPath:@"list.resources.resource.field" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Then in the success block of `RKObjectManager`, the mapping results have the field array. The problem is the `Field`'s property are all `nil`.
I check the log which looks:

```
D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:229 Asked to map source object (
        {
        name = name;
        text = "alpha";
    },
        {
        name = price;
        text = "98.3";
    }

) with mapping  name.text>"
)>
2014-05-14 23:33:57.681 RestKitTest[5138:3307] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:859 Starting mapping operation...
2014-05-14 23:33:57.682 RestKitTest[5138:3307] W restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:338 Destination object  rejected attribute value (
    name,
    price
) for keyPath name.text. Skipping...
```

It seems that the attribute of the xml becomes a value of the map source object. How I set the configuration to parse this kind of object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `Resources` wrapper object (you don't need to) then your response descriptor is drilling too deep into the incoming data, the key path should just be `list`. Turning on trace logging will help you to see how the XML is decoded and thus what keys you should be using. I don't use XML very often and find mapping the XML to keys directly quite difficult.

Note also that the XML decoding will usually add all of the found content into `text` keys, so rather than using `name` as the key you will need to use `name.text` (and thus you will need a dictionary to specify the source key path and the destination key).

Comment: I update the code to add the RKLog. I get the map source object but failed to create the mapping. Could you please take a look?

Comment: You didn't follow my instructions - where did a key path of 'list.resources.resource.field' come from? Also, looking at your XML it might be impossible as everything is a `field` tag. That means you may need to process an array of field dictionaries and write code yourself to extract the contents, which isn't a very good use of RestKit.

Comment: In fact I do not quite understand why can't use `list.resources,resource,field`. However, as you refer, it's an array of attribute dictionaries and I try to parse it without mapping of `RestKit`.